# how can save a list in entity framework code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I have a dictionary detalles
var movimiento_det = new MovimientoDet(); //

```
   foreach (var detalle in detalles)
                            {
                                movimiento_det.MovimientoDetId =   G.Serial("movimiento_det"); // get me the id of the entity
                                movimiento_det.MovimientoDetId= i;
                                movimiento_det.ProductoId = detalle.Value.ProductoId;
                                movimiento_det.Cantidad = detalle.Value.Cantidad;
                                Vmsb.MovimientoDets.Add(movimiento_det);
                            }
                            Vmsb.SaveChanges();
```

I want to save all values of  the dictonary but it just saving to the database the last data in the foreach how can i do to save all the data

using ef5, and vs2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I what is can see movimiento_det is a single object. Each iteration only updates that object. You need to create a new object over each iteration and modify that object.

```
foreach (var detalle in detalles)
{
    var movimiento_det = new MovimientoDet();
    movimiento_det.MovimientoDetId =   G.Serial("movimiento_det"); 
    movimiento_det.MovimientoDetId= i;
    movimiento_det.ProductoId = detalle.Value.ProductoId;
    movimiento_det.Cantidad = detalle.Value.Cantidad;
    Vmsb.MovimientoDets.Add(movimiento_det);
}
Vmsb.SaveChanges();
```